# Exception not handled in catch block

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad

This is my code which is raising exception when i input wrong values in the UITextFields but after raising exception, it is not handled with in the catch statement.

```
- (IBAction)gotocanvas:(id)sender {
    @try {

        DrawObs_Probs *mainview = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"drawCanvas"];
        mainview.length = self.length.text;
        mainview.breadth = self.breadth.text;
        mainview.camheight = self.camheight.text;
        mainview.dataPath = self.dataPath;
        if ([length.text floatValue]==0.0 || [breadth.text floatValue] == 0.0 || [camheight.text floatValue] <= 1.6) {
            NSException* myException = [NSException exceptionWithName:@"Invalid" reason:@"Invalid Input Values" userInfo:nil];
            @throw myException;
        }
        [self presentViewController:mainview animated:YES completion:nil];
    }
    @catch (NSException *exception) {
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error" message:@"Enter values in numbers" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:@"OK", nil];
        [alert show];
    }
    @finally {

    }

}
```

Comment: try..catch is not a very common programming pattern in Objective C.  It certainly doesn't seem warranted here where you can simply use your if statement to display the alert

Comment: any idea how to do it then?

Comment: Just put your `UIAlertView` code where you have the `NSException..` and put the `[self presentViewController:main view animated:yes completion:nil]` in an else clause

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Paul had said don't use try..catch instead use the below method.

```
- (IBAction)gotocanvas:(id)sender {
    if ([length.text floatValue] == 0.0 || [breadth.text floatValue] == 0.0 || [camheight.text floatValue] <= 1.6) {
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error" message:@"Enter values in numbers" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:@"OK", nil];
        [alert show];
        return;
    }

    DrawObs_Probs *mainview = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"drawCanvas"];
    mainview.length = self.length.text;
    mainview.breadth = self.breadth.text;
    mainview.camheight = self.camheight.text;
    mainview.dataPath = self.dataPath;

    [self presentViewController:mainview animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Comment: Thanks and i did the same logic. :)